# Prevent partition from mounting in OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

In older versions of OSX the `/etc/fstab` file was honored and I could put in mount options (in particular, `noauto`).  I have some Carbon Copy Clone bootable backup partitions that I don't want mounted normally. This stopped working in Mavericks; apparently it totally ignores `fstab`.

Is there something I can do to prevent certain partitions from being mounted when I boot in Mavericks?

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward was to do this is to [make an Automator workflow that ejects the partitions](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/automatically-eject-disks-at-boot-in-mac-os-x-with-automator/), then run it at login. In Automator, make a new Application, drag the partition-to-not-be-mounted from the Desktop into the right-hand panel (creates a 'Get specified Finder items' action with the drive as target), add an 'Eject disk action'. Save as an application and add it to login items (System Preferences > Accounts > Login Items).

You could also get the same effect by making a shell script to eject the disk and calling it via launchd at boot or at login.

Also, I'm not able to test right now, but my experience is that when fstab stops working it's usually syntax error... I think it works in Mavericks as it always has. Maybe check your syslog.  Running `sudo mount` can also uncover errors in the fstab.